# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in basic Java GUI interest calculator

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events, action

I'm a pretty novice programmer trying to learn the basics of swing and GUI building. trying to build a Java Gui in which it takes a final double, initial balance, and when a button is pushed, adds a final double 5% interest to it. I keep getting the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at interest.Balance$ButtonListener.actionPerformed(Balance.java:30)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90
```

and can't seem to figure out where I went wrong with this. I don't have nulls and I have no errors in eclipse. I've searched up this problem but it seems to vary case by case. I think that the problem occurs when I try and set text of to the JLabel, but even then im not sure how I'd fix that.

here is my code, I used two different classes for my GUI, BalancePane.java, and Balance.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BalancePane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Balance panel = new Balance();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);  
        frame.setSize(300, 500);    
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Balance extends JPanel {
    private JTextField balanceTextField;
    private final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 1000;
    private final double INTEREST_RATE = 5; 

    public Balance() {
        JButton interestButton = new JButton("Add interest");
        JTextField balanceTextField = new JTextField(10);

        interestButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        add(interestButton);
        add(balanceTextField);

        balanceTextField.setText(Double.toString(INITIAL_BALANCE));
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            double balance = INITIAL_BALANCE * (INTEREST_RATE)/100;
            balanceTextField.setText(Double.toString(balance));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring 2 `JTextField`variables with the same name, initializing one of them and using the other:

[image]

To fix it just change `JTextField balanceTextField = new JTextField(10);` to `balanceTextField = new JTextField(10);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Balance extends JPanel {
    private JTextField balanceTextField;
    // ...
```

`balanceTextField` is a field, initially `null`.

```
    public Balance() {
        // ...
        JTextField balanceTextField = new JTextField(10);
```

Oops. `balanceTextField` is a local variable. The field of the same name is never set.

```
        // ...
            balanceTextField.setText(Double.toString(balance));
```

And this dereferences the never assigned `balanceTextField` field.